# Angular 4, typescript Assign interface property to variable

Tags: angular, http, typescript, bitcoin

Im learning Angular and I'm creating a cryptocurrency exchange app. I created a service and an interface to get the data from an API. Now I can bind it to the DOM but I also want to use this data in my component.ts so I can write for example:

Bid2 = Bid * 2;

and then bind that variable to the DOM like this: {{ Bid2 }}

Thanks for your help. Here is my code:

Component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { BittrexService } from '../../bittrex/bittrex.service';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import { MarketListObject } from '../datosmoneda';
import { MarketPrices } from '../datosmoneda';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-comprarzec',
  templateUrl: './comprarzec.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./comprarzec.component.scss']
})
export class ComprarzecComponent implements OnInit {

  private prices = [];


  constructor(private bittrexService: BittrexService) {
    this.bittrexService = bittrexService;
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.bittrexService.getPrices()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.prices = data.result
  );
}
 }
```

Service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { MarketViewModel } from '../comprarmonedas/datosmoneda'


@Injectable()
export class BittrexService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private marketModel : MarketViewModel) { }

  public getPrices() :Observable<MarketViewModel> {
    return this.http.get('https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummary?market=btc-zec')
    .map((response: Response) => response.json());
  }

}
```

interface.ts (datosmoneda.ts);

```
export class MarketViewModel {
  public success : boolean;
  public message : string;
  public result : MarketListObject[];
}

export class MarketListObject {
    public MarketName : string;
    public High : number;
    public Low : number;
    public Volume : number;
    public Last : number;
    public BaseVolume : number;
    public TimeStamp : number;
    public Bid : number;
    public Ask : number;
    public OpenBuyOrders : number;
    public OpenSellOrders : number;
    public PrevDay : number;
    public Created : number; 

}
```

Thanks for your help again!

Comment: Make a public property of the ComprarzecComponent, and call it Bid2. The template should be able to bind to it. The template should notice when you change the value.

Comment: In interpolation you can make math operations too: {{ Bid * 2 }}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Bid2 = Bid * 2;
>
> and then bind that variable to the DOM like this: {{ Bid2 }}

The first thing worth noting is that for `{{ Bid2 }}` to work, `Bid2` would need to be a property on `ComprarzecComponent`, but `Bid` is a property on `MarketListObject`, so it won't be as simple as just writing `Bid2 = Bid * 2`.  You'll actually need to find the Bid2 for a particular MarketListObject, so it would be more like `Bid2 = prices[index].Bid * 2`.

For example.

*component.ts*

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-comprarzec',
    templateUrl: './comprarzec.component.html',
    styleUrls: [ './comprarzec.component.scss' ]
})
export class ComprarzecComponent implements OnInit {
    private prices: MarketListObject[] = [];

    constructor(private bittrexService: BittrexService) {
    }

    bid2(price: MarketListObject): number {
        return price.Bid * 2;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.bittrexService.getPrices().subscribe(data => {
            this.prices = data.result;
        });
    }
}
```

*comprarzec.component.html*

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let price of prices">
        {{price.Bid}}
        {{bid2(price)}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Going well though, as you're just starting out.  People would generally trip over on the Http stuff first.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe my github could answer some of your questions.

[Ng-CC-Exchange : CryptoCurrencies Exchanges Module for Angular(2+)](https://github.com/ValerianHavaux/Ng-CC-Exchanges)

**An example of how I implement the order book service**

Component

```
getBittrexOrderBook(market) {
if (market !== '') {
  this._bittrexService.getOrderBook(market).subscribe(
    response => {
      if (response.success && response.result) {
        this._tempCurrencyBuy = response.result;
      } else {
        this.handleError(response.message);
      }
    },
    error => this.handleError(error)
  );
}}
```

Models

```
export interface BittrexOrderBook{
    success: boolean;
    message: string;
    result: BittrexOrder[];
}

export interface BittrexOrder{
    Quantity: number;
    Rate: number;
}
```

Html

```
<div class="bittrex-currencies-container">
<div class="bittrex-currencies-sub-container">
    <div class="bittrex-currencies-title">
        <h3 class="bittrex-currencies-title"><strong> Bittrex order book</strong></h3>
    </div>
    <form #form="ngForm" name="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
        <input type="text" class="search-input" placeholder="search engine" [(ngModel)]="filter" name="ngModel">
        <button type="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
    </form>
    <div class="scroll-bar">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="_tempCurrencyBuy.length">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="label label-default" for="bittrex-info-content">Buy orders</label>
                <div class="bittrex-currencies" *ngFor="let currency of _tempCurrencyBuy">
                    <div class="bittrex-info" *ngIf="currency.Quantity">
                        <label class="label label-info" for="bittrex-info-content">Quantity</label>
                        <span id="bittrex-info-content">{{currency.Quantity}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bittrex-info" *ngIf="currency.Rate">
                        <label class="label label-info" for="bittrex-info-content">Rate</label>
                        <span id="bittrex-info-content">{{currency.Rate}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label class="label label-default" for="bittrex-info-content">Sell orders</label>
                <div class="bittrex-currencies" *ngFor="let currency of _tempCurrencySell">
                    <div class="bittrex-info" *ngIf="currency.Quantity">
                        <label class="label label-info" for="bittrex-info-content">Quantity</label>
                        <span id="bittrex-info-content">{{currency.Quantity}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="bittrex-info" *ngIf="currency.Rate">
                        <label class="label label-info" for="bittrex-info-content">Rate</label>
                        <span id="bittrex-info-content">{{currency.Rate}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Using api can become confusing when the api has a CORS problem and that's why there is a Backend with NodeJs and Nodemon to avoid this problem.
With Electron for example the problem is normally solved but for web app it's another story.

Angular without backend

```
getOrderBook(market, type = 'both', depth = 50) {
if (market) {
    return this._http.get(this._BASE_URL + `/getorderbook?market=${market}&type=${type}&depth${depth}`)
        .map(response => response.json() as BittrexOrderBook)
        .timeout(this._timeOut);
    }}
```

If you choose a backend solution here is an example on nodeJS side

```
_api.get(_BITTREX_BASEURL + '/getorderbook', (request, response) => {
console.time("getorderbook");
const market = request.query.market;
const type = request.query.type;
const depth = request.query.depth;
const url = `https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getorderbook?market=${market}&type=${type}&depth${depth}`;
httpGet(url, response);
console.timeEnd("getorderbook");});


function httpGet(url, response) {
    _client.get(url, (data, resp) => {
        response.json(data);
    });
}
```

Another solution may be to use a proxy service as described in this article
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin: Dealing with CORS Errors in Angular](https://daveceddia.com/access-control-allow-origin-cors-errors-in-angular/)

Another point to remember if you want to use something other than the public api of Bittrex. You will need the api keys generated by Bittrex, use post and HMAC-SHA512 (eg: Crypto-js).

[Crypto-js : JavaScript library of crypto standards.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js)